# Retrieve road segment from Google or Bing Maps

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

Let me see if I would be able to explain this correctly... Both Bing and Google Map geocoders can return you and a point given an address. Is there any way to retrieve an 'address range' instead i.e. to get returned a LINE rather than a point?

Its not necessarily address ranges I am after- the key word here is 'line' (along a road). Another example would be to get a road line given 2 points so I would want to get returned the road segment between these 2 points. I assume for this I would need to use the routing functions only?

Another scenario (i guess even more difficult) is given 1 point (along a road) to ask for the road segments for x Km 'up or down' this same road

Hope I am making sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Google Maps API v3 Directions you can achieve this road segment length using waypoints.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints.html

To work out line length
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/3a9f3b83b941a2d7/06792073b2529413?lnk=gst&q=polyline+length#06792073b2529413